# How to free tree effectively

Tags: c, tree, free

How can I free this tree effectively? That algorithm should work for any given node in such tree. So I'll have pointer to node, and that node will be "root" node. And I want to free everything below that node.
[image]

Every node in tree is this struct:

```
  typedef struct tag
  {
      struct tag* parent;
      struct tag* nextSibling;
      struct tag* previousSibling;
      struct tag* firstChild;
      struct tag* lastChild;     
      char* name;
      char* text;     
  }node;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this would work. But in reality, Dariusz is correct. You just use a valid tree traversal, and perform your operation on each node.

*The question changed:* <strike>And since you want this to operate on any node in the tree, just find the root first. It's much easier to write a tree traversal that progresses in one direction, than up and down the tree.</strike>

You've changed the question from deleting a tree, to deleting a subset of a tree. So, instead, let's do this. Remove the element from the tree first (remove_node). and then perform the same free that we would have done before.

```
void remove_node(node *self) {
    if (self->previousSibling)
        self->previousSibling->nextSibling = self->nextSibling;
    if (self->nextSibling)
        self->nextSibling->previousSibling = self->previousSibling;
    if (self->parent && self->parent->firstChild == self)
        self->parent->firstChild = self->nextSibling;
    if (self->parent && self->parent->lastChild == self)
        self->parent->lastChild = self->previousSibling;
}

void free_node(node *self) {
    // Free one node. Perhaps this is:
    free(self->name);
    free(self->text);
    free(self);
}

void iterate_nodes(node *root, void op(node *self) ) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    iterate_nodes(root->nextSibling, op);
    iterate_nodes(root->firstChild, op);
    op(root);
}

int main() {
    node *node = NULL; // Some node in the tree...
    remove_node(node);
    iterate_nodes(node, free_node);
}
```

Comment: But this will free whole tree, won't it? I think I wasn't clear in my question so I've edited it. I want to remove everything below given node and that node itself too.

Comment: @user2213470: And I've changed it. Call `remove_node(node)` and then the `iterate(node, free_node)` and it will remove all children of a given node, and itself from the tree.

Comment: Oh, F5 too strong. Sorry :) Thanks

Comment: @user2213470: note that the only change I made was to include a call to `remove_node`, which makes the remaining tree no longer point to the part we are about to remove, and the rest of the code is identical.

Comment: Won't be there a memory leak after `remove_node` function?

Comment: @user2213470: After remove_node, you have two trees. One is rooted wherever the original one was rooted, and the other one is rooted at the node you passed into remove_node. If you then forget about that variable, then sure it'd be a memory leak. But not until that point.

Comment: 2 more questions. `remove_node(tree)` is calling it with the given node right? not whole tree. And second question, if I want to call it with one function in `int main()`, than can i put `remove_node` into `iterate_nodes`?

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. `iterate_nodes(node, remove_node)` will likely cause a memory leak. If you want to do both in one shot, just write a function that takes a node, calls `remove_node(node)`, and then calls `iterate_nodes(node, free_node)`

Comment: `self->previousSibling->nextSibling = nextSibling;` what should this do? Which nextSibling should it put into `self->previousSibling->nextSibling` ? because it says that nextSibling is undeclared. And in `void iterate_nodes(node *root, void op(node *self)`, shouldn't that be `void iterate_nodes(node *root,op(node *)`?

Comment: I meant `void iterate_nodes(node *root,void (*op)(node *))`

Comment: 1. Fixed. I meant `self->nextSibling`. 2. I believe that's functionally identical, but your version would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Use any of the standard tree-traversal mechanisms and delete all elements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: While I agree that he should use a generic tree traversal, he actually can't ignore the sibling links. A parent in this case only links to the first and last child. If there are three children, then the only way to access it from the parent is `parent->firstChild->nextSibling` or `parent->lastChild->previousSibling`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard post-order tree traversal algorithms to free the whole tree.  To make it work from any given node, just start by traversing all of the parent links to the root.  For example:

```
void free_tree(node *n)
{
    // Find the root node of the tree
    while(n->parent)
        n = n->parent;

    free_tree_helper(n);
}

void free_tree_helper(node *n)
{
    // Free all children of this node in post-order traversal
    node *child = n->firstChild;
    while(child)
    {
        // Save the next sibling pointer to avoid dangling pointers
        node *next = child->nextSibling;
        free_tree_helper(child);
        child = next;
    }

    // All the children have been freed, now free the parent
    free(n->name);
    free(n->text);
    free(n);
}
```

Alternatively, if you use a [memory pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) to allocate your tree nodes, all of your nodes come from the same pool, and the pool contains no other tree's nodes, you can instead just free the entire memory pool at once, saving you from having to traverse the entire tree.  This will be much more efficient, since it avoids a lot of cache misses in a potentially large tree, and it also avoids certain memory fragmentation problems.

Comment: Yea but I don't want to free whole tree, I want to free everything below given node.